# In memory DB with relationships

Tags: c#

I'm reading data from my file system, which I map to classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
}
```

I get a separate `List` for each class type. As you can see above, the classes are related. Instead of reinventing the wheel, are there any frameworks out there that can keep an in memory representation of my data context, with relations? I feel like using something like EF is a bit overkill.

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for an in memory database, or an ORM, or both?

Comment: @mjwills Hmm, I would assume both

Comment: Given you want both, I'd lean towards EF - 
https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-entity-framework-core-in-memory-database-asp-net-core . Overkill perhaps, but it is pretty mainstream at least.

Comment: @mjwills Looks promising! Can it be used for non-core applications though?

Comment: Alas I have not tried that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at XMLSerialiser? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx
Im assuming you're reading data from files in the file system as opposed to just file meta data from the file system!

Comment: If you've got an in-memory representation of the data and have sorted serialisation/deserialisation, don't you already have the in-memory data context you need? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm just thinking that EF might be overkill, if it's the case that EF-style relations in the model is overkill. EF uses relations to map between the relational and hierarchical data model, but as this data is already in a hierarchical model, it's not clear what you want this mapping for?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but for those still bumping into it, a couple of well-established in-memory relational databases that can work for a C# project are:

- [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), which has an [in-memory mode](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) and supports [mapping onto C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48261990/3328536). [Public Domain](https://www.sqlite.org/copyright.html).
- [NMemory Database](https://nmemory.net/) from [ZZZ Projects](https://zzzprojects.com/) which is Open Source and written in C#, [available on GitHub](https://github.com/zzzprojects/nmemory/), and [available as a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NMemory).  [MIT License](https://github.com/zzzprojects/nmemory/blob/master/LICENSE).

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("fo")]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
public Foo fo { get; set; }
}
```

or use fluent api :
[How to get EFCore In-memory db to auto-increment non-key fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078835/how-to-get-efcore-in-memory-db-to-auto-increment-non-key-fields)

or
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration