# How to map C# object to SQLite database table?

Tags: c#, sqlite, object, mapping

I have the following SQLite table

[image]

And I have the following C# classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "articlessql", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
public class Article
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "quantity", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sell_price", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public string SellPrice { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sellid", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public string SellId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "whole_price", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public string WholePrice { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "group", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public string Group { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "barcode", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "measure", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public string Measure { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataSet1", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
public class Articles
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "articlessql", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
    public List<Article> AllArticles { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}
```

I get list of articles like that:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Articles));
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(xmlFilePath);
Articles articles = new Articles();
articles = (Articles)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
textReader.Close();
```

But when I try to insert the list of articles in the table `articles` like that:

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(apkFolder, "MobileSell.db")))
{
    connection.InsertAll(articles.AllArticles);
}
```

It throws exception:

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: Article at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2
```

My question is how can I make the program understand that Article object must be a single row in table `articles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you read SQLite specification?

SQLite has attributes like `[Column]` and `[Table]` attributes. You should use those. Like this:

```
[Table("ContactInfo")] // SQLite attribute
[DataContract(Name = "ContactInfo", Namespace = "")]
public sealed class ContactInfo : DatabaseTableBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique Id of the codebook.
    /// </summary>
    [PrimaryKey] // SQLite attribute
    [AutoIncrement] // SQLite attribute
    [Column("UniqueId")] // SQLite attribute
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override long UniqueId { get; set; }

    [Column("ClaimId")] // SQLite attribute
    [NotNull] // SQLite attribute
    public long ClaimId { get; set; }

    [Column("ContactType")] // SQLite attribute
    [NotNull] // SQLite attribute
    public ContactTypes ContactType { get; set; }

    public ContactInfo()
    {
    }
}
```

In your case, you will be annotating with attributes your class `Article`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Must I put also attributes as `[PrimaryKey]`  `[AutoIncrement]`  etcetera as they are specified in the database table design?

Comment: I am not sure if they are that needed - but looks like it should be even avoided, at least on DB side - https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html .

Also, take in mind that the SQLite does not enforce the type inserted to specific column. For example, you ARE able to insert string into the column that expects only numbers or date time.

Comment: What I know so far, `[Column]` and `[Table]` attributes are essential :) the rest is to constraining :) as I said above - some attributes does not work (or at least, they did not). But with those two, you should not have any trouble :)