# How to get EFCore In-memory db to auto-increment non-key fields

Tags: .net, in-memory-database, ef-core-2.2

We have an entity keyed on a guid with another human-readable key based on an auto-incrementing int property. This works as expected when running the app.

For testing purposes we are using an EF in-memory database but this only seems to auto-increment a column if it also also a key.

Using either the property annotation attribute or the fluent API has no effect.

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderNumber { get; private set; }

    ===========

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(order =>
    {
        order.Property(p => p.OrderNumber).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    });
```

In both cases OrderNumber is left as 0 after insert.  Is there any way of getting the in-memory db to do this, or is this a known limitation?  (Googling has uncovered issues around re-seeding of key values, but not this particular issue)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Value generation of non key properties works differently (don't know why) - it's not triggered when the property has no explicit value generator assigned. For providers that generated temporary keys it works because the actual value is assigned after `SaveChanges`. But in-memory provider value generators generate persistent keys, and since they are not called for non key properties, `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` has no effect (doesn't work).

The workaround is to explicitly assign value generator for such properties. You'd need the following namespace:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.ValueGeneration.Internal;
```

and then a code similar to this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(order =>
{
    var orderNumber = order.Property(p => p.OrderNumber);
    orderNumber.ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    // only for in-memory
    if (Database.IsInMemory())
        orderNumber.HasValueGenerator<InMemoryIntegerValueGenerator<int>>();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also write your own ValueGenerator.

```
public class OrderIdValueGenerator : ValueGenerator<int>
{
    private int _current;

    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override int Next(EntityEntry entry)
        => Interlocked.Increment(ref _current);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(order =>
{
    order.Property(p => p.OrderNumber).HasValueGenerator<OrderIdValueGenerator>();
});
```

You don't have to specify `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`.